# Questions about how to divide and find averages of a dataset

Tags: r, excel

Let's say I have a dataset where I have a list of names and their ages

```
Tom 65
Sam 40
Sue 88
Kay 4
Jon 25
Lia 85
Ian 39
Joe 10
Bea 17
Jan 43
Jen 17
Ike 24
Jay 35
Cam 77
Jin 12
Ron 1
Ray 45
Leo 29
Ken 98
Mel 56
Amy 49
Joy 67
Ivy 3
Noe 14
Max 31
Jax 61
Lee 19
Ace 28
Ben 5
Guy 74
```

I'm trying to divide the dataset into ten equal bins by descending order (Ex. the first bin will have Ken, Sue, and Lia and the last bin will have Ben, Ivy, and Ron) and I want to find the average age for each bin (So the average age for the first bin would be 90.33). I was able to do this on MS excel quite easily but I'm not exactly sure how to do this efficiently on R. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` to create a group and then summarise by taking the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = cut(v2, breaks = 10)) %>% 
    summarise(v1 = list(v1), v2 = mean(v2))
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got these values: grp          V1           V2
   <fct>        <list>    <dbl>
 1 (0.903,10.7] <chr [5]>   4.6
 2 (10.7,20.4]  <chr [5]>  15.8
 3 (20.4,30.1]  <chr [4]>  26.5
 4 (30.1,39.8]  <chr [3]>  35  
 5 (39.8,49.5]  <chr [4]>  44.2
 6 (49.5,59.2]  <chr [1]>  56  
 7 (59.2,68.9]  <chr [3]>  64.3
 8 (68.9,78.6]  <chr [2]>  75.5
 9 (78.6,88.3]  <chr [2]>  86.5
10 (88.3,98.1]  <chr [1]>  98 I don't know if I see the mean such as the 90.33 for the first bin.

Comment: @tangerineGrapes Your description is `m trying to divide the dataset into ten equal bins by descending order`, `cut` splits into bins based on the values and i specified 10 bins, then I did the summarise.

Comment: Yes, and the summarise isn't giving me the correct mean.

Comment: Ken, Sue, and Lia's average age is around 90.33 ((98+88+85)/3)). The next 3 oldest so Cam, Guy, and Joy's average age is around 72.67. I don't see those numbers in the output.

Comment: @tangerineGrapes the cut split based on a default method.  If you are comparing with excel method, it may use a different algorithm for splitting

Comment: Yes but it should provide the same output given that the names and the corresponding ages are divided into 10 different bins and it finds the average age of each of the bins.

Comment: It is doing the breaks on the numeric column.  Please check how in excel it is doing that